# rosserial installation [solved]

Tags: ros, arduino, installation, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have ROS electric [installed from source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) - ROS-Base: (Bare Bones) ROS package

now i have try to install rosserial as shown in [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup):

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial
```

ok

```
rosdep install rosserial_arduino
```

and got error:

```
Warning: could not identify ['rosserial_arduino'] as a package
...
rosdep: error: No Valid Packages or stacks listed as arguments
```

what i have to do?
and how cold i install over Dependencies packeges?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11589/rosserial-installation-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-19**:
question about this error  -http://answers.ros.org/question/2568/rosdep-error-conflicting-rosdep-definitions

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-19**:
ERROR: QUITTING: due to conflicting rosdep definitions, please resolve this conf
lict.
Rules for python-sip4 do not match:
python-sip4-dev sip4 [/home/ubuntu/ros/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml]
python-sip-dev [/home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/rosdep.yaml]

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-19**:
ok. id rosinstall nedded packages but got error on rosdep install rosserial_arduino:

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-18**:
now - i cant rosmake without dependencies. How i could install common_msgs stack from source?

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-18**:
Ok. Id edit ~/ros/setup.sh and add rosserial path into $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
roslocate info rosserial > rosserial.rosinstall
rosinstall ~/ros rosserial.rosinstall
```

but on
rosdep install rosserial_arduino
get error - [conflicting rosdep definitions](http://answers.ros.org/question/2568/rosdep-error-conflicting-rosdep-definitions)

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1